# Minimalizing HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to minimalize HTML content?

For example, let's say I have a regular HTML document such as:

```
<html>


<title>A title or something</title>  

  <h2>Blah blah blah times 5 </h2>
  <p>
  Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5Blah blah blah times 5
  </p>


</html>
```

I would rather if possible do something like this:

```
<html>


<title>{title of page}</title>  

  <h2>{header information}</h2>
  <p>
{Paragraph information}
  </p>


</html>
```

I'm not sure how the html page would know it's getting that information but I'm looking just to see if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use a library like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). There are other similar libraries out there as well so take care to research which is best for you.

Handlebars will allow you to use the `{{something}}` format to minimise the information you code into your html. Others will use a similar, if not the same, format.

Building on that, you could also switch to using an MVC framework (such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Ember](http://emberjs.com/)) which include similar "mustache" style templating and other helpful features in order to make your dynamic content easier to code. Ember actually uses Handlebars, Angular uses it's own "directives" which are very similar. Other MVC frameworks with included templating are available as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking about using some kind of UI templating framework. It's possible to do, it can be done server-side or client-side, each has it's pros and cons.

Since you tagged the question with `javascript` and `jquery` here are a few client-side templating frameworks that you may find useful:

- [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Also take a look at [Template Engine Chooser](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Answer (score 1):

What do you plan on using to populate your HTML? I usually use

`<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <title></title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        </head>
        <body>
         <h1>{{jsonResponse.whatever}}</h1>
        </body>
      </html>`

as my minimum markup to start off with and then have angular fill in the rest where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `JavaScript` to place contents programatically

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'title of page';
document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'header information';
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = 'Paragraph information';
```

```html
<html>
  <title></title>  
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a downside to using this versus what other people suggested like handlebars and angular?

Comment: This is pure javascript while others are library.